# How to skip update when parameter is null/0 in spring batch with JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

We have a scenario wherein while doing a batch update on a table using `JdbcBatchItemWriter`, We are not finding a way to not update is the attribute is `null`. We don't want to have too many queries and `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` so we have a single query to update all fields in the table. Different batch jobs set update different attributes of the table

```
List<Report> summaryList = getSummaryList()    
JdbcBatchItemWriter<ItemMktDcGpReport> writer1 = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
String sql_update = GenericConstants.UPDATE_QUERY;
writer1.setDataSource(dataSource);
ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Report> updatePreparedStatementSetter = new ItemMergeUpdatePreparedItemSetter();
writer1.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(updatePreparedStatementSetter);
writer1.setSql(sql_update);
writer1.afterPropertiesSet();
writer1.write(summaryList);
```

Tried the following seeing few examples on conditional update at the query but it doesn't help yet.
Below is the query. Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

```
UPDATE_QUERY = "update  [dbo].[test_tbl]  
SET test_col1 = CASE When ?!=0  then ?
else test_col1 end ,
test_col2 =  CASE When ?!=0  then ? 
else test_col2 WHERE  market=? and country = ?"
```

I don't want to construct the SQL query based on parameter as I will lose out on the bulk writing feature of `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. Can someone please suggest the right approach to solve this problem and possibly correct the SQL query I'm writing?

Comment: Your usage of the writer is weird. Looks like you ar using SPirng Batch classes outside of Spring Batch, without using the proper job, step, chunks. That being said, you might be better of by writing a proper job and have a reader that reads the summary, then a processor that fills in the `null`s with the values from the database and then have a simple writer again.

Comment: or maybe even better, use `coalesce` to determine the non null part. something like `UPDATE [dbo].[test_tbl] SET test_col1 = coalesce(?, test_col1), test_col2 = coalesce(? test_col2) WHERE market=? and country=?`. Nonetheless the way you are using the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is still weird.

Comment: I second what M. Deinum said. The update sql query is not the place to do conditional updates. I recommend to use an item processor to prepare the data as needed before being sent to the database for writing. The processor should either filter `null` or update them to non-null or default values. Any reason you are not using a regular Spring Batch job with a chunk-oriented step?

Comment: Agree with prior commenters but incidentally what DB are you running?